# XCode 12.5 won't allow me to add Swift packages. Package resolution failed. <folder> exists and is not an empty directory (-4)

Tags: swift, xcode

What do I need to do to resolve this?

I can't add Swift packages to my project without XCode 12.5 complaining about a folder that didn't exist there prior to adding the package using Swift packages -> Add package dependancy.

I've tried

- Reinstalling XCode
- Deleting DerivedData
- Clean Build folder
- Reset package caches
- Resolve package versions
- Update to latest package versions

The image below shows ViewInspector failing, but that seems stochastic. The error occurs when fetching SwiftUI-Introspect every other time as well. This hints at a race condition somewhere. It doesn't matter which package I try to add, The folder in deriveddata will be created and XCode will complain and abort.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to remove and then add your package? I remember it helps me sometime.

Comment: @iUrii Yes, I get the same issue. It's upon fetching that the error occurs. It doesn't matter if the package is already added in the repository or not.

Downgrading to XCode 12.4 seems to work though.